# Hover Effect Transform property

Tags: html, css, hover, transform

I am trying to make a gallery, the links show up from the bottom on
hover. I am having trouble regarding hiding them when they are not on hover.

I am trying to make a gallery, the links show up from the bottom on
hover. I am having trouble regarding hiding them when they are not on hover.
I am trying to make a gallery, the links show up from the bottom on
hover. I am having trouble regarding hiding them when they are not on hover.
I am trying to make a gallery, the links show up from the bottom on
hover. I am having trouble regarding hiding them when they are not on hover.
I am trying to make a gallery, the links show up from the bottom on
hover. I am having trouble regarding hiding them when they are not on hover.

```css
.imageWrapper {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .imageWrapper img {
        display: block;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .imageWrapper .cornerLink {
        height:100px;
        width:200px;
        opacity: 0.7;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: cadetblue;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        transform: translateX(0) translateY(100px) translateZ(0);
        transition-duration:0.3s;
        transition-property: transform;
        
    }
    .imageWrapper:hover .cornerLink {
        transform: translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0);
    }
    a{
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
        <main>
        <div class="imageWrapper">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
            <div class="cornerLink">
            <a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="imageWrapper">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
            <div class="cornerLink">
            <a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="imageWrapper">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
            <div class="cornerLink">
            <a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="imageWrapper">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
            <div class="cornerLink">
            <a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
            </div>

        </div>
            
            
        </main>
    </body>
```

Comment: can you add your code

Comment: do you mean when you hover on the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden;` to your `.imageWrapper` class. Here's working code:

```css
.imageWrapper {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .imageWrapper img {
        display: block;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .imageWrapper .cornerLink {
        height:100px;
        width:200px;
        opacity: 0.7;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: cadetblue;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        transform: translateX(0) translateY(100px) translateZ(0);
        transition-duration:0.3s;
        transition-property: transform;
        
    }
    .imageWrapper:hover .cornerLink {
        transform: translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0);
    }
    a{
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<body>
        <main>
        <div class="imageWrapper">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
            <div class="cornerLink">
            <a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="imageWrapper">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
            <div class="cornerLink">
            <a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="imageWrapper">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
            <div class="cornerLink">
            <a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="imageWrapper">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
            <div class="cornerLink">
            <a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
            </div>

        </div>
            
            
        </main>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Change this line `transform: translateX(0) translateY(100px) translateZ(0);` to `transform: translateX(0) translateY(115px) translateZ(0);`</strike>:

Add `overflow:hidden` to `.imageWrapper` to remove the space under images

```css
.imageWrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden; /* Hides links when off image */
}
.imageWrapper img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.imageWrapper .cornerLink {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(0) translateY(100px) translateZ(0);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: transform;
}
.imageWrapper:hover .cornerLink {
  transform: translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0);
}
a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="imageWrapper">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
      <div class="cornerLink">
        <a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="imageWrapper">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
      <div class="cornerLink">
        <a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="imageWrapper">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
      <div class="cornerLink">
        <a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="imageWrapper">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
      <div class="cornerLink">
        <a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
      </div>

    </div>


  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: thnx a lot...!!

Comment: With the purpose achieved, I deleted my comment... Sorry about that, not great with names. :)